# IIS redirect FQDN to application's name

Tags: iis, iis-7, url-rewriting

I am looking to redirect

```
https://ourapplication.ourdomain
```

to

```
https://ourapplication.ourdomain/foldername/default.asp
```

I have created a rule in URL rewrite that says:

```
<rule name="test" stopProcessing="true">
                <match url="^https://ourapplication.ourdomain/$" />
                <action type="Redirect" url="{R:0}/foldername/default.asp" />
                <conditions>
                    <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="ourapplication.ourdomain" />
                </conditions>
 </rule>
```

I have tried other rules but they were unsuccessful. Tried rewrite as well as redirect.

Comment: I ended up fixing this by making changes to the code itself instead of using a redirect or rewrite, but still would like to find out how this can be done using the IIS URL rewrite module